# How to remove multiple header rows from dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas

I have 4 csv files with same format and a header row as first row in each file. I merged these in a dataframe using the below code:

```
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, [file for file in glob.glob('data/*.csv')]))
```

Now, I realize that the headers from each file would be in the data and will cause problems in analysis. Is there a way to remove all headers other than the first?

Answer (score 0):

Need this?

```
df = (
    pd.concat(
        (pd.read_csv(file)
         if index == 0
         else
         pd.read_csv(file).iloc[1:]
         for index, file in enumerate(glob.glob('data/*.csv')))
    )
)
```

Comment: I can see the logic in your code. Pretty good and thanks for sharing this. However, this gave me same number of rows as my code.  Does it mean my code also eliminated the headers after the first file?

Comment: @l4tech can you share 2/3 sample CSV just a few rows of each?